# Why model.fit function in keras significantly increase RAM memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I load my data with open_memmap function and it takes 5GB RAM memory. Then I compile the model which has params: 89,268,608 and it does not take any RAM memory. My batch size is 200 at the moment and the input image has shape (300,54,3).

My problem is when I call the model.fit function in keras my RAM memory increase from 5 GB to 24GB. My question is why?

When I try with different batch sizes nothing is changing and still 23 GB of RAM are occupied?

If somebody can explain me what is happening I would highly appreciate it,

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keras' `fit` method loads all the data into memory at once meaning changing your batch size will have no effect on the RAM it takes up. Have a look at using [fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) which is designed for use with a large dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I already loaded the data in RAM before calling model.fit. Is it loading it again, so I have the same data twice in RAM?

Comment: It is not loading it again. The additional memory is from the model itself. The size of memory needed for the model depends on the type of network you are implementing, their layers, activations, etc.