# Is memory supposed to be this high during model.fit using a generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The tensorflow versions that I can still recreate this behavior are: `2.7.0`, `2.7.3`, `2.8.0`, `2.9.0`. Actually, these are all the versions I've tried; I wasn't able to resolve the issue in any version.

- OS: Ubuntu 20
- GPU: RTX 2060
- RAM: 16GB

I am trying to feed my data to a model using a generator:

```py
class DataGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, indices, batch_size):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.indices = indices
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        X_batch = self.X[self.indices][
            index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size
        ]
        y_batch = self.y[self.indices][
            index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size
        ]
        return X_batch, y_batch
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y[self.indices]) // self.batch_size

train_gen = DataGen(train_indices, 32)
val_gen = DataGen(val_indices, 32)
test_gen = DataGen(test_indices, 32)
```

where `X`, `y` is my dataset loaded from a `.h5` file using `h5py`, and `train_indices`, `val_indices`, `test_indices` are the indices for each set that will be used on `X` and `y`.

I am creating the model and feeding the data using:

```py
# setup model
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(128, 128, 3),
                                                include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False

mobilenet1 = Sequential([
    base_model,
    Flatten(),
    Dense(27, activation='softmax')
])

mobilenet1.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                   loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
# model training
hist_mobilenet = mobilenet1.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=1)
```

The memory right before training is 8%, but the moment training starts it begins getting values from 30% up to 60%. Since I am using a generator and loading the data in small parts of 32 observations at a time, it seems odd to me that the memory climbs this high. Also, even when training stops, memory stays above 30%. I checked all global variables but none of them has such a large size. If I start another training session memory starts having even higher usage values and eventually jupyter notebook kernel dies.

Is something wrong with my implementation or this is normal?

##### Edit 1: some additional info.

- Whenever the training stops, memory usage drops a little, but I can decrease it even more by calling garbage collector. However, I cannot bring it back down to 8%, even when I delete the history created by fit
- the x and y batches' size sum up to 48 bytes; this outrages me! how come loading 48 of data at a time is causing the memory usage to increase that much? Supposedly I am using HDF5 dataset to be able to handle the data without overloading RAM. The next thing that comes to my mind is that `fit` creates some variables, but it doesn't make sense that it needs so many GBs of memory to store them

Comment: Can you be explicit about what memory you are referring to: Resident Memory? Virtual Memory? GPU Memory? But in general I would expect substantial memory usage during training. There will be a pipeline of operations with caching along the way. Can you comment on the specific process that is increasing in memory usage? I recommend `glances` as better than `top` or `htop` for tracking these kinds of things.

Comment: I am referring to resident memory. Swap memory is always high, so I guess it's not its fault that the kernel crashes. VRAM gets high (4.4/6.4) after loading the first model, but I don't think that this is the problem. The process name is `/usr/bin/python3 -m ipykernel_launcher`, but I am not sure to what you are referring to.

Comment: I can see the batch size is 32, which is pretty normal for your decent configuration, Why didn't you use data generator from keras library `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311198/why-model-fit-function-in-keras-significantly-increase-ram-memory

Comment: @AshwinRaikar I did try to combine it with loading data from an HDF5 file, but even then RAM would get as high as 40%. Then I tried creating my own generator, which brought same results.

Comment: @lazy The answer in the first link is to create a generator, this is exactly the problem I am facing: high RAM during fitting with generator. The other two articles are about high VRAM, which is not *my* problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### How to minimize RAM usage

From the very helpful comments and answers of our fellow friends, I came to this conclusion:

- First, we have to save the data to an HDF5 file, so we would not have to load the whole dataset in memory.

```py
import h5py as h5
import gc
file = h5.File('data.h5', 'r')
X = file['X']
y = file['y']
gc.collect()
```

I am using garbage collector just to be safe.

- Then, we would not have to pass the data to the generator, as the X and y will be same for training, validation and testing. In order to differentiate between the different data, we will use index maps

```py
# split data for validation and testing
val_split, test_split = 0.2, 0.1

train_indices = np.arange(len(X))[:-int(len(X) * (val_split + test_split))]
val_indices = np.arange(len(X))[-int(len(X) * (val_split + test_split)) : -int(len(X) * test_split)]
test_indices = np.arange(len(X))[-int(len(X) * test_split):]


class DataGen(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, index_map, batch_size):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.index_map = index_map
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        X_batch = self.X[self.index_map[
            index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size
        ]]
        y_batch = self.y[self.index_map[
            index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size
        ]]
        return X_batch, y_batch
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.index_map) // self.batch_size

train_gen = DataGen(train_indices, 32)
val_gen = DataGen(val_indices, 32)
test_gen = DataGen(test_indices, 32)
```

- Last thing to notice is how I implemented the the data fetching inside `__getitem__`.

Correct solution:

```py
X_batch = self.X[self.index_map[
            index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size
        ]]
```

Wrong solution:

```py
X_batch = self.X[self.index_map][
            index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size
        ]
```

*same for y*

Notice the difference? In the wrong solution I am loading the whole dataset (training, validation or testing) in memory! Instead, in the correct solution I am only loading the batch meant to feed in the `fit` method.

With this setup, I managed to raise RAM only to 2.88 GB, which is pretty cool!

Answer (score 5):

Literally, this is not a generator. When you instantiate DataGen, you create a complete class with full indices (def **init** (self, indices, batch_size)), with datasets (self.X, self.Y), with inheritance from Sequential, and so on.

The simplest real generator for tensorflow looks something like this:

```python
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

BATCH_SIZE = 32
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
X_val = X_train[int(len(X_train) * 0.8):]
X_train = X_train[int(len(X_train) * 0.8)]
y_val = y_train[int(len(y_train) * 0.8):]
y_train = y_train[:int(len(y_train) * 0.8)]

def gen_reader(X_train, y_train):
    for data, label in zip(X_train, y_train):
        yield data, label

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_reader, args=[X_train, y_train], output_types=(tf.float64, tf.int8)).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_reader, args=[X_val, y_val], output_types=(tf.float64, tf.int8)).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_reader, args=[X_test, y_test], output_types=(tf.float64, tf.int8)).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

...

hist_mobilenet = mobilenet1.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=1)
```

Comment: I understand what you've said, and I understand why my generator is causing RAM usage to be high. But, even in your implementation, you load `X_train`, `X_val` and so on, which take up space in memory. Isn't your implementation supposed to take the same space as mine? I will also test it and add the information to this comment.

Comment: I think his implementation is using less space as he used **yield** in his generator instead of **return**.
 
Check this link Yield vs Return in python 
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-python-yield-and-python-return/

Comment: @AshwinRaikar I think you are right, it is using less memory, but I think that is because there are less passes by value in the code, not because of `yield`. You could do the same thing with a `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` using `return` if you had the data loaded by reference, and then using  an index map to access only training data, or a different index map to access validation data.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `fit_generator` instead of the `fit` method

I mean instead of

`hist_mobilenet = mobilenet1.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=1)`

Use

`hist_mobilenet = mobilenet1.fit_generator(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=1)`

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54311198/why-model-fit-function-in-keras-significantly-increase-ram-memory) it says

> Keras' fit method loads all the data into memory at once meaning
> changing your batch size will have no effect on the RAM it takes up.
> Have a look at using which is designed for use with a large dataset.

I think the fit_generator will load data batch-wise and not take up the whole ram instantly.

Comment: `fit_generator` is deprecated and should not be used. Instead, fit supports generators. \href{https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380430/how-to-use-model-fit-which-supports-generators-after-fit-generator-deprecation}{check this link}

Comment: @BillTheKid Have you tried using **yield** instead of **return** in the `__getitem__(self, index):` generator ?……I would like to replicate your scenario on my system but I guess your data might be confidential.

Comment: No, I have not, but I will. The data I am working on can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ardamavi/27-class-sign-language-dataset